# Make programs (specifically chrome) open on same virtual desktop

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, virtual-desktop

Windows has virtual desktops which is great. I use separate desktops for different things I am working on.
But if I close a program (or reboot), then when I open the program again the program appear on the desktop I am currently on. So I manually have to move the program back.

I guess for chrome it is even more complicated as it is the same program with different windows. It would be nice to have the windows stay on the desktop they were before closing.

Similar to these issues with the difference of my question asking to remember windows position as opposed to setting it explicitly.

- [How to open program on a specified virtual desktop on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1157906/how-to-open-program-on-a-specified-virtual-desktop-on-windows-10)
- [Windows 10: Assigning Application to Specific Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/956884/windows-10-assigning-application-to-specific-desktop)
- [Starting Programs in a Specific Virtual Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/961227/starting-programs-in-a-specific-virtual-desktop)
- [How do I open a program directly to a specific virtual desktop with powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1236644/how-do-i-open-a-program-directly-to-a-specific-virtual-desktop-with-powershell)
- [Chrome instances move to same virtual desktop after sleep or hibernate in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1125446/chrome-instances-move-to-same-virtual-desktop-after-sleep-or-hibernate-in-window)
- [How to open a program on particular desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/236526/how-to-open-a-program-on-particular-desktop)

EDIT (2022): All these workarounds seem unnecessary now. Chrome will now open windows on the desktop they were when chrome was closed.

Comment: In order to achieve your workflow you would need to use a third-party utility to manage your application instances (i.e. windows).  What you want is not possible with the built-in Virtual Desktop feature.

Comment: OK. But is there a program that can do it? I.e. remember last position across virtual desktops and hopefully somehow also work when multiple instances (e.g. chrome) are used.

Comment: There were virtual desktops thanks to third-party developers long before it was introduced in Windows 10.  However, if they function exactly how you want, I couldn't say one way or another.  I am also unable to provide any specific recommendations for obvious reasons.

Comment: How can the windows be identified? Do they have the same title when relaunched after the boot?

Comment: Chrome seems to use the same name for all windows so I don't think that can be done. In https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl?hl=en you can assign names but I think they are internal to the extension.

Comment: In my experience separate Chrome windows on different websites have distinct titles.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1017188/windows-10-virtual-desktops-preserve-taskbar-order

Comment: All these workarounds seem unnecessary now. Chrome will now open windows on the desktop they were when chrome was closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the below [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) script,
which accepts two shortcut keys:

- <kbd>F11</kbd> : Will write the titles of all current windows and their
  virtual desktop numbers to a text file specified in the parameter `FILENAME`
  that is found at the beginning of the script.
- <kbd>F12</kbd> : Reads the text file and moves all the windows it can find
  by their title to the specified virtual desktop.

Copy the following text into an `.ahk` file, possibly changing "FILENAME",
"F11" and "F12".
Double-click the file to start it executing. It will create a green "H"
icon in the traybar that you can right-click and select `Exit` to stop.
If you always want this script to execute, copy it to the user Startup folder at
`C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

This script requires to download from the Github project
[windows-desktop-switcher](https://github.com/pmb6tz/windows-desktop-switcher)
the DLL
[VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll](https://github.com/pmb6tz/windows-desktop-switcher/raw/master/VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll)
and storing it in the same folder as the AutoHotKey script.
It might not work for Windows 10 versions below 1809.

The script itself is below and is programmed for only one monitor.
It does not create the virtual desktops, so they should be created
before running it.
It worked for me, but should be tested.
As it's using undocumented features, it might
stop working some time in the future.

```
DetectHiddenWindows Off
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

FILENAME = C:\Temp\possaves.txt

hVirtualDesktopAccessor := DllCall("LoadLibrary", Str, "VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll", "Ptr") 
MoveWindowToDesktopNumberProc := DllCall("GetProcAddress", Ptr, hVirtualDesktopAccessor, AStr, "MoveWindowToDesktopNumber", "Ptr")
IsWindowOnDesktopNumberProc := DllCall("GetProcAddress", Ptr, hVirtualDesktopAccessor, AStr, "IsWindowOnDesktopNumber", "Ptr")

global numdesktops := GetDesktopsNumber()

F11::  ; Write list of "desktop@title"
EnumAddress := RegisterCallback("EnumWindowsProc", "Fast")
global numwins := 0
global file := FileOpen(FILENAME, "w")
DllCall("EnumWindows", "Ptr", EnumAddress, "Ptr", 0)
file.Close()
return

F12::  ; Read list and execute
global result
Loop, Read, %FILENAME%
{
    word_array := StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine, "@",, 2)  ; Omits periods.
    hwnd := WinExist(word_array[2])
    if (hwnd)
        DllCall(MoveWindowToDesktopNumberProc, UInt, hwnd, UInt, word_array[1] - 1)
}
return

GetDesktopsNumber()
{
    RegRead, cur, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SessionInfo\1\VirtualDesktops, CurrentVirtualDesktop
    RegRead, alldesktops, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VirtualDesktops, VirtualDesktopIDs
    return floor(strlen(alldesktops) / strlen(cur))
}

EnumWindowsProc(hwnd, lParam)
{
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %hwnd%
    if title {
        desktopnum := GetHWNDDesktopNumber(hwnd)
        if (desktopnum >= 0) {
            numwins := numwins + 1
            line = % desktopnum "@" title "`r`n"
            file.Write(line)
        }
    }
    return true
}

GetHWNDDesktopNumber(hwnd)
{
  global  numdesktops, IsWindowOnDesktopNumberProc
  Loop, %numdesktops% {
    ix := A_Index - 1
    windowIsOnDesktop := DllCall(IsWindowOnDesktopNumberProc, UInt, hwnd, UInt, ix)
    if (windowIsOnDesktop == 1)
      return A_Index
  }
  return -1
}
```

Comment: Will this work with chrome? I imagine all window titles will be the same?

Comment: The Chrome window title contains the website's title, so titles of Chrome windows for different websites are not the same.

Comment: Have you tried the script?

Comment: Not yet. I will get around to it this weekend I hope. I am sorry but it seems I screwed up with the bounty by being to slow.

Comment: Yes you did do that.

Comment: I am very sorry it took so long to come back to this. I tried it and it didn't work out of the gate. I had windows version 1803 and 1903 available. It did however work very well for both once I tracked down the right version of VirtualDesktopAccessor (this worked https://github.com/Ciantic/VirtualDesktopAccessor/blob/365b39e7019c921628ce2d26b777509c0d0507cc/x64/Release/VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll). Thank you so much!

Comment: There is one caveat though. Chrome windows' titles are in the format "2@Tab title - Google Chrome". Thus it will only work if you are on the same tab as when you saved the positions. I tried to see if there was a way to make the window name "sticky" and found http://superuser.com/q/908196#answer-1018889 that works. Unfortunately that is not persistent to Chrome restarts which was the point.
The only problem with @harrymc's solution is if you change tab after saving. That is only likely when Windows reboots on its own but I guess the script could be schedule.

Comment: After an update this stopped working for me. Does it still work for anyone else? Version 1903 (build 18362.592)

Comment: Of interesting. I ran it once as admin. and now it suddenly somewhat works. But the file only contains a list of what is on the desktop I am on.

Comment: Also as an exe it works. But I only get what is on the desktop I am on when I trigger the script.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is basically the same as @harrymc with following improvements:

- Works on the latest Window 10 (v2004 as of this writing)
- Saves the browser window assignments in the background (every 5 minutes)
- Uses URL to (more reliably) identify browser windows
- Compatible with "The Great Suspender"
- Backup support

AHK script https://github.com/onefork/windows-desktop-switcher/releases

PM me if you need a .exe file instead.

Comment: What about windows 11?

Answer (score 1):

I tried harrymc's solution and it worked fine on a Win10 64-bits, v1903. The solution allows to record multiple Chrome windows running in different virtual desktops (Fn+F11).  If all Chrome windows appear in the same virtual desktop after reboot, using (Fn+F12) sends each Chrome window to the recorded virtual desktop.

I tried with 50 Chrome windows distributed over 10 virtual desktops. It took 2-3 seconds to generate the file.

@harrymc: Thank you very much! For some reason I need to press Fn+F11 or Fn+F12 in my laptop.  The F11 and F12 keys alone do not trigger the functions of the AutoHotKey script.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to configure plain Windows like that but this issue can be solved by using third-party lightweight utility called VDesk (https://github.com/eksime/VDesk). It allows you to create shortcuts that will start programs on specific virtual desktops.

It also allows to start programs on different virtual desktop without switching to it (in fact running that app hidden until you manually switch to that desktop) which is very handy feature.

Specifically for Chrome you can create different Windows on different desktops by creating shortcuts looking like this (and then just clicking them):

```
vdesk on:3 run:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /new-window "https://superuser.com"
```

(above will run superuser.com on desktop #3)

Comment: Yes I saw this elsewhere too. But it would require you to pre-define websites. It is not very handy for keeping active work organized where you will open lots of different pages.

Comment: You don't have to pre-define websites. If you want 3 desktops - one for Work, one for School and one for Fun you still can pre-open one generic empty Chrome Window on each of them. For example, I use VDesk to setup my workflows. On desktop I use for code reviews it opens Chrome Window and Terminal, while on desktop I use for coding it opens my editor, debugger and also Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

It is said to be fixed since version 88 of chrome, so using the beta at this point is a solution. Or you can simply wait for its release on 19.01.2021.

There was a bug open for this at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1065557
It was reported for Unix and X11 earlier and marked fixed there, however on my machine it doesn't work with Ubuntu and Google Chrome 87 either. 88 seems to have fixed it on my Ubuntu with a brief test.

Comment: Unclear to me why this was down-voted. The issue linked appears to be about this.

Comment: I thought proper etiquette would be to provide an explanation for a down vote. I will gladly improve my answer with the help of constructive criticism.