# Windows 10 separate windows to separate desktops when disconnecting from extended dual monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I have a laptop running Windows 10 Pro. I use this laptop for mobile computing and as a desktop. As a desktop, it's connected to an external monitor, mouse, and keyboard. I unplug the laptop from the monitor multiple times per day to take it with me.

I set windows to use the external monitor as the primary monitor when connected and for the laptop's monitor to "extend" it. When I disconnect the external monitor, all the windows from both monitors are moved to a single desktop. Everything is now a mess and I have to spend a lot of time getting reorganized. How can I make it so that, instead of combining the windows to a single desktop, it will instead create a separate virtual desktop containing the windows from each connected monitor?

Comment: There is no such option, although it is possible (but not too easy) to write a script that does that.

Comment: I've written bash scripts but never scripts in Windows. What are some relevant functions of windows scripting? Can you point me to some documentation? If not, it's ok, I'll find it.

Comment: A related example is [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1477582/8672).