# Is there a way to restore chrome tabs (and windows) to different desktops using the same chrome instance?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, restore, virtual-desktop, session

I'm looking for a way to restore chrome windows from the same chrome instance (e.g. using the same [`user-data-dir`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md)) to different [windows desktops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_View).

Using chrome with one [profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) and one [`user-data-dir`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) i have many windows spread over different Windows 10 Desktops.

For this profile i'm using the following startup setting:

[image: google-chrome onStartup settings]

When closing and reopening chrome, all windows and tabs are restored, including position and  size but not including the desktop; they all land on the first desktop, even though while closing they were spread over multiple desktops.

It would be possible to create one environment per desktop using [`user-data-dir`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) but that would split history and everything else.

Is there a way without using third party tools to make chrome restore the windows to their original desktop having just one [profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) and one [`user-data-dir`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md)?

There's [a similar question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1408214/make-programs-specifically-chrome-open-on-same-virtual-desktop?rq=1) with an edit from 2022:

> All these workarounds seem unnecessary now. Chrome will now open
> windows on the desktop they were when chrome was closed.

but it seems that doesn't include windows spread over multiple desktops.